# Weka: ArffSaver writeIncremental() not writing to file

Tags: weka

i am trying to create an ARFF file using ArffSaver. (i am actually converting an non-arff file that is very large.)

i am trying to write the file incrementally using the writeIncremental(Instance insntance) method. unfortunately, each call to writeIncremental() results in data being written to System.out -- not to the designated file.

here is a clip of my code:

```
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
  ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
  saver.setDestination(out);
  saver.setRetrieval(Saver.INCREMENTAL);
  saver.setStructure(instances);
  String s = null;
  while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
     Instance instance = toInstance(s, instances);
     saver.writeIncremental(instance);
  }
  saver.writeIncremental(null);
```

any ideas on how i can get the ArffSaver to write incrementally to the file?

Comment: You should show how your outFilename is defined

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this and works fine:

`saver.setFile(new File(outputFile));

saver.setDestination(new File(outputFile));`

Comment: setDestination isn't necessary with recent Weka versions (3.5.4 or later according to docs).